# Custom X Axis Label on JFreeChart DTSC

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a JFreeChart to display speed variation. I have used MilliSecondDTSC and MultipleOfMilliSeconds classes to display 10 samples per second (100ms refresh rate). On X-Axis, it shows current time. I want that X-Axis should start with 00:00:00 and increase with time rather than current time, is there any way to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Java epoch as your baseline:

```
Date date = new Date(0L);
```

Set the format and time zone you want on your domain axis:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
domain.setDateFormatOverride(df);
```